# install arch gitlab and can not git clone using ssh method

Tags: ssh, gitlab, archlinux

I followed, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GitLab#Configuration, and finally brought gitlab it up. But, I could not use ssh to clone the project.

```
$ ssh -T gitlab@192.168.48.3
Failed to get username: who='' is invalid
```

What is this message `who=''` and how to debug???

Using ssh -Tv, I got

$ ssh -T gitlab@192.168.48.3

```
Failed to get username: who='' is invalid
[alexlai@N2eMMc128G ~]$ ssh -Tv gitlab@192.168.48.3
OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.48.3 [192.168.48.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.48.3:22 as 'gitlab'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:TbXi96Gynm1xqcTglDvS4ajP7hPHMHf2hnOiJ3w5e74
debug1: Host '192.168.48.3' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alexlai/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:tdOYKwO8CDOzJeJo/6WYbtStpsMg8kuSGLCie5JOY1g
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:tdOYKwO8CDOzJeJo/6WYbtStpsMg8kuSGLCie5JOY1g
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/alexlai/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:tdOYKwO8CDOzJeJo/6WYbtStpsMg8kuSGLCie5JOY1g
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.48.3 ([192.168.48.3]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /var/lib/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /var/lib/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
Failed to get username: who='' is invalid
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3468, received 3288 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 39481.4, received 37432.2
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: As stated in the documentation you linked in reference, the ssh system username used by Gitlab for clone/push/pull operations is **`git`** not `gitlab`.

Comment: Please be noted that arch linux distribution does not create a git user as documented in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GitLab#Configuration.  Thanks anyway,